# How to disable inline CSS source maps

Tags: angular-universal

I have recently published my website as server rendered (with transition) and I used https://gtmetrix.com to analyse it, one of the warnings was: "Minify HTML" and then I noticed there was tons of CSS sourcemaps as inline data URLs.

I have no idea how to remove them, I already call `enableProdMode()` in my `server.ts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer by searching into JSON schema into `./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json` since documentation doesn't mention it:

```
"server": {
   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
   "options": {
      "outputPath": "dist/server",
      "main": "src/main.server.ts",
      "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
      "sourceMap": false
   },
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, my and my team were getting desperate with this.